# Java Applet Can't Access Files

Tags: java, html, japplet

I am trying to launch a Java Applet through from a signed jar using an HTML file. The applet works fine when I run it from Netbeans, but I understand this is because of security limitations placed on applets. The error message I received is related to the program need read access to a particular file.

After some searching online I found that doPrivileged() should be used for this behavior, so I added that in my code, but I am still receiving the error message.

HTML -

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Launch Applet</title>
<body>
<tr>
<td><center>
    <applet
        archive=widget.jar
        code=widget.class
        width=1100
        height=1100>  
    </applet>
</center></td>
</body>
```

Function in Java -

```
class OpenThread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try {
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
                public Object run() {
                    if(new File(path+"\\loadFile.txt").exists()){
                         System.out.println("true");
                    }
                     return null;
                }
            }); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I trimmed down the thread for debugging purposes, eventually the txt file will be used in the code again. I'm not sure if my JAR file was signed incorrectly, if the MANIFEST file in the jar should contain file permissions, or if I have to edit my java.policy file. Any ideas?

Comment: *"..need read access to a particular file."*  This 'particular file' is supplied by you or the end user?  Is it read only or intended for read/write?  Also - why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: This is not for an assignment from a teacher. I need to embed a Java application into a web browser, and I was under the assumption that an applet was the only way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two basic choices. You can create a policy file, giving the applet access to the local file system.  There is a detailed tutorial here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.html

Your other choice is to launch the applet using JNLP.  This will give you access to all sorts of resources on the local computer.  This is the shortest path.

Comment: I need to embed my applet into a browser, so I'm not sure if the policy file route is avoidable. I am have generated the policy file using the tool from the supplied link and when I use "Djava.security.policy=policyfilename" when running the appletviewer from the command line I still get the same results. Am I incorporating the policy file wrong?

Comment: It's been a long time!  The only thing I can think of is that the policy file isn't being found. I remember java looks in your home directory by default, and that you can specify the location with -Djava.security.policy=policyfilepath

Comment: This worked! Now to debug the rest of the code. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted the answer, although I can't plus up until I have more reputation.

Comment: I'll push you on your way!